# Kotlin IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/.kotlin_string_table

Tags: android, classpath, kotlin

I'm trying to play around with Kotlin a bit in my Android app and am having trouble calling extension functions. The app crashes immediately with the following stack trace:

```
04-23 13:31:22.415  32606-32606/com.example.kotlin.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kotlin.test, PID: 32606
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.reflect.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.kt:34)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.InternalPackage$moduleByClassLoader$cff17278.getOrCreateModule(moduleByClassLoader.kt:54)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:31)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:26)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.get(ReflectProperties.java:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getScope(KClassImpl.kt:43)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:72)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage$KClassExtensions$6beb0f9b.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:25)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:1)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.DatabaseObject$$TImpl.deflate(DatabaseObject.kt:40)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.deflate(Model.kt)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.<init>(Model.kt:28)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.TestModel.<init>(TestModel.kt:23)
            at com.example.app.TestModelIndexFragment.onCreate(TestModelIndexFragment.java:122)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Built-in library initialization failed. Please ensure you have kotlin-runtime.jar in the classpath:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/.kotlin_string_table
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.initialize(KotlinBuiltIns.java:75)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getInstance(KotlinBuiltIns.java:93)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMapBuilder.init(JavaToKotlinClassMapBuilder.java:35)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMap.<init>(JavaToKotlinClassMap.java:44)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMap.<clinit>(JavaToKotlinClassMap.java:35)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.reflect.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.kt:34)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.InternalPackage$moduleByClassLoader$cff17278.getOrCreateModule(moduleByClassLoader.kt:54)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:31)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:26)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.get(ReflectProperties.java:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getScope(KClassImpl.kt:43)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:72)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage$KClassExtensions$6beb0f9b.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:25)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:1)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.DatabaseObject$$TImpl.deflate(DatabaseObject.kt:40)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.deflate(Model.kt)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.<init>(Model.kt:28)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.TestModel.<init>(TestModel.kt:23)
            at com.example.app.TestModelIndexFragment.onCreate(TestModelIndexFragment.java:122)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/.kotlin_string_table
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.BuiltinsPackageFragment.getStream(BuiltinsPackageFragment.kt:86)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.BuiltinsPackageFragment.<init>(BuiltinsPackageFragment.kt:55)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.<init>(KotlinBuiltIns.java:114)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.initialize(KotlinBuiltIns.java:70)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getInstance(KotlinBuiltIns.java:93)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMapBuilder.init(JavaToKotlinClassMapBuilder.java:35)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMap.<init>(JavaToKotlinClassMap.java:44)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.JavaToKotlinClassMap.<clinit>(JavaToKotlinClassMap.java:35)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.reflect.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.kt:34)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.InternalPackage$moduleByClassLoader$cff17278.getOrCreateModule(moduleByClassLoader.kt:54)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:31)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$descriptor$1.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:26)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.get(ReflectProperties.java:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getScope(KClassImpl.kt:43)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:84)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getProperties(KClassImpl.kt:72)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage$KClassExtensions$6beb0f9b.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:25)
            at kotlin.reflect.ReflectPackage.getDeclaredProperties(KClassExtensions.kt:1)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.DatabaseObject$$TImpl.deflate(DatabaseObject.kt:40)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.deflate(Model.kt)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.Model.<init>(Model.kt:28)
            at com.example.test.kotlin.api.model.impl.TestModel.<init>(TestModel.kt:23)
            at com.example.app.TestModelIndexFragment.onCreate(TestModelIndexFragment.java:122)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

My project is composed of two modules, `test-kt` and `app`, for the new Kotlin stuff and existing Java code respectively. `test-kt/build.gradle` has the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '0.11.91.2'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

I've tried adding the Kotlin libs as dependencies within `app` as well with no luck. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Upon further investigation, it looks like this only happens whenever I use property references (such as `::x`) and not when I use extension methods. I definitely have included `kotlin-reflect`... any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is a current issue with current Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this as well when upgrading to Kotlin version 0.11.91.2. There is apparently an issue where the Android toolset does not pack a file prepended with a dot into resources. (note that the file the exception references, .kotlin_string_table, is prepended with a dot).

[A fix](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/20cd360b077b558f7b1af0a2063e7ea908b64efd) has been written but not yet released. You can try using the snapshot release of Kotlin in order to take advantage of it, or otherwise just wait for the next update.